# getSelection with multiple occurrence of text replaces first occurrence not the correct selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, getselection

I am having a hard time selecting text and replacing that selection when there are multiple occurrences. It always reverts to the first occurrence and replaces it.

Here is the scripting I am using and if the selection only appears once I am prefect. When it appears more than once it grabs the first.

```
var self=$('#textarea');
GetSelected={};
GetSelected=function(){
    var txt='';
    if(window.getSelection){
        txt=window.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        txt=document.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        txt=document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return txt;
}

self.html(self.html().replace(selection, '<b>' + selection + '</b>'));
```

Is there something I am missing, that know which selection to replace?

Answer (score 0):

To replace all the occurrence you need to use `/g`. Please try `self.html(self.html().replace('/' +selection+'/g', '<b>' + selection + '</b>'));`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that treating HTML as a string and replacing parts of it as your are doing is a very fragile approach (think of a matching piece of text where part of it is already bold, or an attribute value that contains match the selected text, for example). Instead, you could use [built-in browser behaviour to find matching text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags/5887719#5887719). Here is the function from that question adapted for your case:

```
function doSearch(text) {
    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
        document.designMode = "on";
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

        while (window.find(text)) {
            document.execCommand("Bold", false, null);
            sel.collapseToEnd();
        }
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        while (textRange.findText(text)) {
            textRange.execCommand("Bold", false, null);
            textRange.collapse(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the `GetSelected` function is incorrect (although it coincidentally does work in this case) in that it returns a string in IE < 9 and a `Selection` object in other browsers. You also haven't declared the `GetSelected` variable. Here's a simpler and better replacement:

```
function GetSelected() {
    var txt = ""
    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return txt;
}
```

Note that you don't need this function at all if you use my suggested approach.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to find the text, you'll need to act on the selection itself.  This will be different depending on the browser:

```
var t = $("#textarea")[0];
if (t.setSelectionRange)
{
    var selStart = t.selectionStart;
    var selEnd = t.selectionEnd;
    var val = t.value;
    var startVal = val.substring(0, selStart);
    var selectedVal = val.substring(selStart, selEnd);
    var endVal = val.substring(selEnd);
    var bold = selectedVal.bold();
    t.value = startVal + bold + endVal;
}
else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange)
{
    var selection = document.selection.createRange();
    selection.text = selection.text.bold();
}
```