# Create Safari's Find Function Style Text Selector in Javascript

Tags: javascript, selection, highlighting, highlight, textselection

Is there any way to make this text selection effect easily with a library in Javascript? It is very well done and I'd like to mirror this look.

Wondering if anyone had done something similar or seen it done before and if they could provide any guidance. Thanks!

[image: Safari Find Function Text Selector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [on-page text highlighting Search with jQuery](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/833/on-page-text-highlighting-Search-with-jQuery) and
- [On-Page Text Search](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/09/21/5-coding-techniques-for-more-dynamic-websites/#on-page-text-search).

The style is quite similar to the Safari implementation.

Comment: These won't work for text that crosses element boundaries (e.g. search for "development is" in the first example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.find()` in most browsers and `TextRange`'s `findText()` method in IE to find all occurrences of a particular string in the page, and then use `execCommand()` to style each occurrence. See [Full text search in HTML ignoring tags / &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags/5887719#5887719) for an example. This won't give you the curvy corners and drop shadow but is a starting point. It also doesn't work in Opera.

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain? If I've misunderstood the question (which I may have) then it would be helpful to explain how.

Comment: I'd also be curious to hear why this was downvoted. Tim, thanks for the response, you didn't get into the styling and I'm not sure if this is technically correct but I'd love to hear from dissenter. Cheers.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, thanks Tim. If new info comes to light this might change!