# How to keep old highlights when calling window.find() again

Tags: javascript, firefox

If I use the below code I am able to highlight the found text in Window.

```
 window.find(str);
```

But if I search for another string with [`window.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find) the previous highlight will be removed. But how can I change that to not remove old highlights..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.execCommand()` to add styling to the current selection after calling `window.find()`. See my answer here, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5887719/96100

Comment: this is partially working in IE. Could you please look into this post please... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284266/need-a-small-improvement-in-this-function

Comment: @user1008575: It works fine for me in IE 7. I don't have IE 8 on my current PC. Could you describe an example case where it doesn't work?

Comment: It seems that is bug in IE8 textrange object. That is considering html object also along with text.

Comment: @user1008575: I still don't really know what you mean without a concrete example.

Comment: I have taken the text as <span>I</span> am in the body and searched for I am. In IE8 it was taking(AOL version) html tags along with text. And the function you have written is unable to find the text in my site with Window.find(text).. It is always returning me false.. Could you please let me know any corrections in the code..