# This does not highlight text only in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, window, find

Here is the code I got from [Full text search in HTML ignoring tags / &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags/5887719#5887719) and it is not highlighting in case of Mozilla..

```
 function doSearch(text) {
if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
    document.designMode = "on";
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

    // Till here works in Mozilla But the below line is not matching even if the text is found in window. But works fine in Google Chrome

    while (window.find(text)) {
        document.getElementById("button").blur();
        document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false,"yellow");
        sel.collapseToEnd();
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
} else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var textRange =document.body.createTextRange();
    while (textRange.findText(text)) {
        textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false,"yellow");
        textRange.collapse(false);
    }
  }
 }
```

Is there any alternative mode to deal with Mozilla?
Please have a look at this and suggest if any code need to be needed.

Comment: have you got the link where you got it from?

Comment: @david Updated the post name in the Question text

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla) have 'hiliteColor' and 'backColor' with lower-case first letters - might that be it?

Comment: @Rup: No, command names are case insensitive in `execCommand()`.

Comment: This code works in Mozilla in the jsFiddle example in the original answer you linked to. If you have an example of it not working in Mozilla, it would be helpful to create an example of it not working (using jsFiddle, for instance).

Comment: @tim down The data is very secure..So I cannot post the code. Please accept my apologies..