# how to search and hilight text containing special characters using javascript/jquery/c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full text search in HTML ignoring tags / &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags)

I did lots of googling but didnt find any help.
I have a webbrowser control wchich has HTML body.Body contains data that includes special charactors also. I want to add search box wchich will search and hilight it in page .Text can include special characters like \,/,?,$,^,&,<,> .
how should i achieve this using jquery/javascript or c#?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I gave to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887719/96100

However, [`window.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find), which the above answer relies on, [is likely to be removed from browsers in the future](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Jun/0283.html) and is not going to be replaced in the short term. That being the case, I've written a flexible search function for my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library. Demo (with highlighting) here:

http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html