# search page function for internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I need to put a search page function in the site that I'm working on.  I found one online and it works great in Firefox and Chrome but not at all in IE.  I think the fact that I didn't write this code is making it particularly hard to debug. Any help or guidance is appreciated!

HTML

```
<form id="f1" name="f1" action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="searchpage()" >
<input id="t1" type="text" name="t1" />
<input id="button" type="submit" value="FIND" name="b1" onclick="searchpage()" />
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function searchpage() {
    if (document.getElementById("t1").value != null && this.document.getElementById("t1").value != '') parent.findString(document.getElementById("t1").value);
    return false;
}
var TRange = null;

function findString(str) {
    if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) < 4) return;
    var strFound;
    if (window.find) {
        // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find
        strFound = self.find(str);
        if (!strFound) {
            strFound = self.find(str, 0, 1);
            while (self.find(str, 0, 1)) continue;
        }
    }
    else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE
        if (TRange != null) {
            TRange.collapse(false);
            strFound = TRange.findText(str);
            if (strFound) TRange.select();
        }
        if (TRange == null || strFound == 0) {
            TRange = self.document.body.createTextRange();
            strFound = TRange.findText(str);
            if (strFound) TRange.select();
        }
    }
    else if (navigator.appName == "Opera") {
        alert("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
        return;
    }
    if (!strFound) alert("String '" + str + "' not found!") return;
}​
```

it is also important to note that while this works in Firefox and Chrome, the "string not found!" alert box doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version dapted from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887719/96100).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MRp2G/5/

Code:

```
function doSearch(text) {
    var sel;
    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            sel.collapseToEnd();
        }
        window.find(text);
    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        sel = document.selection;
        var textRange;
        if (sel.type == "Text") {
            textRange = sel.createRange();
            textRange.collapse(false);
        } else {
            textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.collapse(true);
        }
        if (textRange.findText(text)) {
            textRange.select();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow!  thank you so much!  in all my searches, I couldn't find it! thanks for helping me out!

Comment: so now I'm trying to make a drop down list with options so you can search specific categories in the table.  I've got all the columns sorted by ids.  Any idea how to go about doing this?

Comment: @user1634292: Which bit is tripping you up?

Comment: well, I've got the simple html code for the drop down lists and my table is sorted into divs but I can't figure out how to connect the function with the divs? What method would I use? I tried inserting getElementById() after the document calls but I kept getting error messages.

Comment: @user1634292: A demo page would probably help.

Comment: Okay, after working on this for awhile, I've figured out how best to phrase the question : How do I use your script to search only certain divs instead of the entire document?