# How to highlight all text occurrences in a HTML page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really thought this would have been answered years ago, still I did not find any solution:

I want to highlight (i.e. make a colored background) all occurrences of a (sub-)string on an entire HTML page, completely client-side with JavaScript.

Just as you would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search inside Google Chrome: When entering the search term, it highlights all the substrings that match my entered term.

Personally, I would walk all elements of the DOM tree, doing some `replace` of the search term with something like

```
<span style="background-color: yellow">MySearchTerm</span>
```

But I think there must be some more effective way?

**My question:**

How to use JavaScript (or jQuery) to highlight all substring occurrences inside a HTML page?

Comment: What you describe is the only way ... the only *improvement* might be to use a class instead of inline-styling..

Comment: Just a quick note that there is also [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) with a [Highlighter Module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/HighlighterModule).

Comment: And [yet another highlighting example](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/).

Comment: The best way would be [mark.js](https://markjs.io)

Answer (score 7):

I struggled to find a robust text highlighter that duplicates the browsers <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> functionality for months. I've used a host of jQuery plugins. Some are better than others but none are capable of spanning HTML. Say you want to find text that includes a link - the browser can do it but no jQuery plugins I've found can.

Turns out bare naked javascript has the answer. Just `window.find()`.

```
find(string, matchcase, searchBackward)
```

string : The text string for which to search.

matchcase  : Boolean value. If true, specifies a case-sensitive search. If you supply this parameter, you must also supply backward.

searchBackward :  Boolean. If true, specifies a backward search. If you supply this parameter, you must also supply casesensitive.

It highlights html laden strings and it's compatible with every browser you care about. Read more about it at http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/window-find.php

The unfortunate thing is you can't seem to do anything with it. I can't wrap it in styled span tags, get the position, scroll to it or change the highlight colour. I'm still looking for the ideal <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> JS function.

Answer (score 6):

[Window.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) should do the job.

Although it is not standardised yet, almost all major newer-version browsers support it, such as Google Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera, and browsers on iPhone/Android/Amazon Fire tablets and phones, etc.

Below is a sample implementation:

```
/*
 * Search for text in the window ignoring tags
 * 
 * Parameters:
 *     text: a string to search for
 *     backgroundColor: 
 *         "yellow" for example, when you would like to highlight the words
 *         "transparent", when you would like to clear the highlights
 * */
function doSearch(text, backgroundColor) {
    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
        document.designMode = "on";
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

        while (window.find(text)) {
            document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, backgroundColor);
            sel.collapseToEnd();
        }
        document.designMode = "off";
    }
}
```

The code is from Tim Down' [implementation using Window.find()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887719/2700356)

Before the search, the HTML text looks like:

```
<p>Here is some searchable text with some lápices in it, and some
    <b>for<i>mat</i>t</b>ing bits, and a URL
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google Search Engine</a> as a link.
</p>
```

Once you've search for text, for example, `some lápices in it, and some formatting bits, and a URL Google`, the HTML text will change to:

```
<p>Here is some searchable text with <span style="background-color: yellow;">some lápices in it, and some
    <b>for<i>mat</i>t</b>ing bits, and a URL
    </span><a href="https://www.google.com"><span style="background-color: yellow;">Google </span>Search Engine</a> as a link.
</p>
```

See [the code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyougo/7rzjarny/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to highlight the search terms from google then you can use this jquery plugin available at https://github.com/hail2u/jquery.highlight-search-terms

If you want functionality like chrome. you can use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var search = ['p', 'div', 'span'];

  $("#highlighter").bind('keyup', function(e){
    var pattern = $(this).val();

    $.each(search, function(i){
        var str = search[i];        
        var orgText = $(str).text();

        orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
          return "<span style='background-color: red;'>" + $1 + "</span>"
        });

        $(str).html(orgText);
    });    
  });
});
```

Comment: I would not use this. If the text contains HTML code then it will be injected without escaping.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for doing this is usually, somewhat surprisingly, to *not* do it.

Rely instead on the built-in search feature of the web browser: This ensures that users have a consistent experience, and saves you a lot of trouble in having to double the work that has already been done to allow for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually this is for a limited-user-base Intranet application that has a search field. I would not do this in the public, for our users, it seems to be helpful :-)

Comment: @UweKeim: If it's a limited-user-base application, all the more reason to simply teach them to use Ctrl-F. ;)

Comment: Then they have to search _twice_, once in the HTML form field, and then afterwards once in the browser. I really want to show them the matches right after the first search.

Comment: Even the Google search does this by making the SERP entries with **bold** substrings for the detailed matches. Maybe I'll change from background color to bold.

Comment: @UweKeim: The issue is that the built-in search function does a lot more than just highlighting, it also does stuff like jumping to the next occurrence, and other neat stuff like that. Unless you are planning on implementing that as well, the user will necessarily end up with an inferior product, and that's no good.

Comment: @UweKeim: Google also gives a very short, contextual excerpt.