# Regular expression: search for and wrap characters '(re.a)' with '<b>$1</b>' in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sentence which has the following:

"I am a very long (ng.a) sentence"

now I am after a regular expression (or means) in JavaScript to be able to search in that sentence for example any of the following combinations: 'ng', '(ng.', 'ng.a', 'long (', 'ng.a)' , etc..

I wish to be able to highlight the found text by wrapping it with a '`<b></b>`' tag. there may well be more than 1 instance of the given search so for example if you search for the letter 'e' then ALL occurrences of the letter 'e' would have the '`<b></b>`' wrapped around it making it '`<b>e</b>`'.

The same goes for if you typed in the letters 'ng.a', as there is only 1 occurrence of this then that would be wrapped making it '`<b>ng.a</b>`'.

How can I do this using a regular expression?

Many thanks for your help on this in advance.

(amendments made for clarity of the issue)

***Secondary amendments...Please read***

I have found a regular expression that is close to what I am after, the code is:

```
var words = 'this is a ng. word (ng.a)' 
var result = words.replace(/[(]?(ng\.)[)]?/gi, '<b>$1</b>');
```

but this returns:

```
'this is a <b>ng.</b> word <b>ng.</b>a)'
```

...notice that the left bracket has been removed!

the result should be:

```
'this is a <b>ng.</b> word (<b>ng.</b>a)'
```

if the search word was not to be '`ng.`' and it was '`(ng.a)`', then the result should be:

```
'this is a ng. word <b>(ng.a)</b>'
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251505/how-to-highlight-all-text-occurrences-in-a-html-page-with-javascript

Comment: BTW: I might be wrong, but I see no reason for using Regex here at all.

Comment: @Keim you are of course right but I assumed that quinton was asking a general question or else would have simply used string.replace

Answer (score 0):

```
// Something like:
var x='this is a very (re.a) long sentence'
var y = x.replace(new RegExp('\\(re\\.a\\)'),'<b>$&</b>')
console.log(y) // prints "this is a very <b>(re.a)</b> long sentence"

// alternatively you don't have to escape the \ in /re/ style
var y = x.replace(new RegExp(/\(re\.a\)/),'<b>$&</b>')
```

Comment: But you have to escape the period `.`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can you please look at the above change to my question. How would I deal with such an issue? your solution would work if I knew I would 'always' have brackets surrounding the text but this it not always the case. Thanks!

Comment: @quinton, can you please clarify - are you looking for regexp syntax or some other control? RegExp has other flags (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) like "g" for global replace. BTW, you can accept my answer if you find it usable :)

Comment: I have detailed a better clarification to what the issue is and how far I have come to nearly resolving it. this is a difficult one to crack! Thanks for your help on this Dinesh :)