# how to check if a string contains substring and color it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to create:

- 1 `<input type="text">`
- 1 `<textarea>`
- 1 `<div>`
- 1 `<button>`

I have to fill the `div` with the `textarea`'s content but if the content contains the `input`'s string, I have to color it with `<span>`.

For example:

If the `input` contains *"is"* and the `textarea` contains *"this is a beautiful day"*, I should put the following text in the `div` *"this is a beautiful day"* and color every time that the *"is"* string appears.

I should use `indexOf()` and a loop.

I have this:

```
var a = $("#inp1").val();
var b = $("#txt").val();

var x = b.indexOf(a);
    if (x > -1)
```

Comment: where is the div, the button, the textarea and the input?

Comment: You now know the position of `b` in `a`. You can split your string and recreate it, your `b` wrapped in a styled span. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: color what? The matched word or all the text.

Comment: @rikpg For what do you need it?

Comment: I have already posted an answer related to highlighting the text in jQuery. I hope it would be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251505/how-to-highlight-all-text-occurrences-in-a-html-page-with-javascript/16251584#16251584

Comment: homework can be tough, eh? :/

Comment: I have ti color the matched word. The inpur is on the top then the textarea and then the div, the button is in the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely have to use indexOf

```
while(b.indexOf(a) != -1) {
   b = b.replace(a, '[X]');
}
while(b.indexOf('[X]') != -1) {
   b = b.replace('[X]', '<span style="color:yellow;">' + a + '</span>');
}
$("#targetDiv").html(b);
```

You can also do this with RegExp

```
var a = $("#inp1").val();
var b = $("#txt").val();
var re = new RegExp(a, 'g');
var divContent = b.replace(re, '<span style="color:yellow;">' + a + '</span>');
$("#targetDiv").html(divContent);
```

Here is a fiddle with the indexOf

http://jsfiddle.net/eva3ttuL/1/

Comment: Can you explain me what is the ['x'] refers to?

Comment: It's just a placeholder, since you wanted to use `indexOf`. Since I'm replacing a string with the same string in a span element; it would be an infinite loop :)

Comment: if i replace the string with the same string in a span element ( .replace(a, '<span style="color:yellow;">' + a + '</span>'). why would it be an infinite loop?

Comment: Because `indexOf` will find the `a` string again, since you put it in there again :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to find and change color of all searched word

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#here").on("keydown keyup", function () {
        var mytext = $(this).val();
        var find = $("#find").val();
        mytext=mytext.replace(new RegExp(find,"g"), "<span class='me'>"+find+"</span>");
        $("#output").html(mytext);

    });
})
```

```css
  .me{color: #00f;
  background-color: #EFFF00;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="find" type="text" /><br/>
<textarea id="here"></textarea><br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript `substring` to split the string inside textarea and form a `paragraph` with the highlighted text.

HTML code:

```
<input id="inp1" type="text"/><br>
<textarea id="txt" col="10" row="5"></textarea><br>
<div id="fillarea">
    click on check
</div>
<button id="check">check</button>
```

CSS for highlighting:

```
.highlight{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#check').on('click',function(){
    var a = $("#inp1").val();
    var b = $("#txt").val();
    var x = b.indexOf(a);
    var first = b.substring(0,x);
    var middle = b.substring(x,x+a.length);
    var last = b.substring(x+a.length,b.length);
    var to_print = '<p>' + first + '<span class="highlight">' + middle + '</span> ' + last + '</p>';
    $('#fillarea').empty();
    $('#fillarea').append(to_print);
});
```

Demo fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9zL3yed2/2/)

Comment: that could be good but notice that if i write in the input: "ab" and in the the textarea: "deabchab", only the first "ab" is highlight. I have to highlight everytime that "ab" appears

Comment: @moral17592 I didn't notice that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It helps you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6w6nd2fr/)

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
    var content = $('.textarea').val();
    var ans = content.replace($('.input').val(), "<span style='color:red;'>"+$('.input').val()+"</span>");
    $('.text').html(ans);
});
```

Comment: Apparently, the poster is supposed to use `indexOf()`. Also, this only highlights the first instance of `$('.input').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $("#inp1").val();
var text = $("#txt").val();
var div = $("#div");

div.val(text.replace(new RegExp(input,'g'), makeSpan(input)));

function makeSpan(str) {
  return '<span style="background-color:red">' + str + '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```html
<html>
  <title></title>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var a = "is";
   var b = "this is beautiful";
    
    var x = b.indexOf(a);
    
     if (x > -1) {
      var re = new RegExp(a, 'g');
      res = b.replace(re, "<span style='color:red'>"+a+"</span>" );
      $("#result").html(res);
     }
  })
 
 </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **IndexOf** Javascript function

```
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
var str2 = "DEFG";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
    alert(str2 + " found");
}
```

Comment: have dare  to face then comment here.....without giving Explanation You have no right to do this.....