# how to use MARK.JS (or any plug in) with WEBDRIVER throught JAVA to highlight all instances of specified word in web page

Tags: highlight

I want to write an auto-test to check spelling in web pages using web service's API and highlight the words which are detected as incorrect for the following printscreening to file as a bug report proving.

Searching the web i've understood that the only way to highlight a separate word is to use JavaScript via JavaScriptExecutor.

I've found how to highlight web elements containing incorrect words, but unable to carry out separate word highlighting.

So, after collecting some information i have made next steps:

- uploaded mark.js plugin on github
- put the external .js into the DOM
- set string with word
- called mark.js on html body of the page:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

  driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251505/how-to-highlight-all-text-occurrences-in-a-html-page-with-javascript");

  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
  .executeScript("var addscript=window.document.createElement('script');addscript.type='text/javascript';addscript.src='http://github.com/my3tahk/codekeep/blob/master/mark.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(addscript);");

  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
  .executeScript("return typeof(somefunc)").toString().equals("function");

  String word = "text";

      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
      .executeScript("var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector('body.context'));instance.mark('"+ word +"', {'element': 'span','className': 'highlight'});");
  ```

Console returns:

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Mark is not defined`

**My question**: How to correctly use mark.js (or another suggested plug in) in this case.

P.S.: Due to i'm newbie, please give a detailed description with full explanations.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, but seems like mark.js wasn't loaded. GitHub answers with wrong headers, you may have success using a CDN like [this](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/7.0.2/mark.min.js).

Comment: @dude, thx for your advice. The problem stays, but now console returns different  errror:               `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: can't convert null to object`

Comment: If this was caused by mark.js then either your context or your options are wrong. Does `body.context` exist? Also your call to instance.mark should look like `instance.mark(word)` instead of `instance.mark('"+ word +"')`, but note that `word` must be defined in JavaScript, not just in your Java script

Comment: I've used `document.querySelectorAll('body')` instead `document.querySelector('body.context')` and this have done the trick. Thanks for hits, @dude.

Answer (score 0):

1. i've used cdn.jsdelivr.net instead of .js posted on github. (thx to @dude)
2. `document.querySelec‌​torAll('body')` must be used instead of `document.querySelec‌​tor('body.context')`

**the result working code**:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251505/how-to-highlight-all-text-occurrences-in-a-html-page-with-javascript");

((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
  .executeScript("var addscript=window.document.createElement('script');addscript.type='text/javascript';addscript.src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/7.0.2/mark.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(addscript);");

((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
 .executeScript("return typeof(somefunc)").toString().equals("function");

String word = "text";

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("var instance = new Mark(document.querySelectorAll('body'));instance.mark('"+ word +"', {'element': 'span','className': 'highlight'});");
```