# Highlighting duplicate words in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I have a table that contains **v-html** results (thus the text inside the table would not be there until the page is rendered). I would like to compare two rows and if they have duplicate words then they should be highlighted.

Here is an [example project](https://codepen.io/finnhvman/pen/oPwXRa) of what I wanted, but way beyond the scope of what I need. My question seems most like [this one in the stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251505/how-to-highlight-all-text-occurrences-in-a-html-page-with-javascript) but it requires that the words be defined, I want the page to find them itself.

For example, this would be the expected output:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td v-html="link.orderdesciption">
    order:<br />
   <mark> TV </mark><br /> <!--note that the contents of the td would not appear in markup due to being v-html-->
    PS3 <br />
    Laptop
    </td>
    <td>
    qty:<br />
    1<br />
    2<br />
    1<br />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    ----------------
    </td>
    <td>
    ----------------
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td v-html="link.orderrecieved">
    recieved:<br /> <!--same note as above, v-html only shows-->
    <mark> TV </mark><br />
    Desktop<br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've been working on this but I have really no idea where to go from here:

```
var text = $('td').text(),
    words = text.split(' '),
    sortedWords = words.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateWords = [];


for (var i=0; i<sortedWords.length-1; i++) {
    if (sortedWords[i+1] == sortedWords[i]) {
        duplicateWords.push(sortedWords[i]);
    }
}
duplicateWords = $.unique(duplicateWords);
```

Thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` to get the `duplicate words`, then you can iterate over `tds` to check in the text in it is present
within the duplicate words Array. If yes, then wrap the the text in `mark` tag.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');

const groupByOccurence = [...tds].reduce((accu, td) => {
  const textArr = td.innerHTML.split('<br>').map((word) => word.trim()).filter((word) => word.length > 0 && word.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g));
  textArr.forEach((text) => {
    accu[text] = (accu[text] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return accu;
}, {});

const duplicateWords = Object.entries(groupByOccurence).filter(([_, val]) => val > 1).map(([key, _]) => key);

tds.forEach((td) => {
  const textArr = td.innerHTML.split('<br>').map((word) => word.trim());
  let str = "";
  textArr.forEach((text) => {
    if (duplicateWords.includes(text)) {
      str += '<mark>' + text + '</mark><br>';
    } else {
      str += text + '<br>';
    }
    td.innerHTML = str;
  })
});

const trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

trs.forEach((tr, i) => {
  const specialChartds = [...tr.querySelectorAll('td')].filter((td) => !td.textContent.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g));
  if (!specialChartds) {
    tr.append(tds[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      order:<br /> TV
      <br /> PS3 <br /> Laptop
    </td>
    <td>
      qty:<br /> 1
      <br /> 2
      <br /> 1
      <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ----------------
    </td>
    <td>
      ----------------
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      recieved:<br /> TV <br /> Desktop
      <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is close but it fails to grab a value posted by v-html, it's like it doesn't see it

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Getting all words from table by looping $('table') with each
2. Creating array with all duplicate words from step1 using filter method
3. Looping all tds with each and adding mark tag for duplicate words

```js
var text = $('table');
var arr = [];

//Step 1: Getting All words from table
var words = text.each(function(){
   let val = $(this).text().replace(/\n|\r/g,' ').split(' ').filter(Boolean);
   arr.push(...val)
})


//Step 2: Finding duplicate words
let duplicate = arr.filter(function(value,index,self){ return (self.indexOf(value) !== index && isNaN(parseInt(value)) && value.match(/[A-Za-z]/) !== null)})


//Step 3: Marking duplicate words in each row
$('td').each(function(){
   let val = $(this).text();
   let openMark = '<mark>'
   let closeMark = '</mark>'
   duplicate.forEach(v => {
      if(val.indexOf(v) !== -1){
          var html = $(this).html().replace(v, openMark + v + closeMark)
          $(this).html(html)
      }
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    order:<br />
   TV<br />
    PS3 <br />
    Laptop
    </td>
    <td>
    qty:<br />
    1<br />
    2<br />
    1<br />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    ----------------
    </td>
    <td>
    ----------------
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    recieved:<br />
    TV<br />
    Desktop<br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YoPPMv?editors=1010

Comment: It looks like this isn't working with v-html, I've clarified my post a bit so there is less confusion.