# can't get text highlighted when multiple tags are present

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to highlight text by selecting it and clicking the button (labeled get highlighted text).

This is the implementation of it:

http://jsbin.com/uzILUro/1

Part of the `html` that has multiple tags is not getting selected.

i.e. try to select the below paragraph and highlight it by clicking the button.

`"The remainder is r when p is divided by k" means p = kq + r; the integer q is called the quotient. For instance, “The remainder is 1 when 7 is divided by 3” means 7 = 3·2 + 1. Dividing both sides of p = kq + r by k gives the following alternative form p/k = q + r/k.`

All the other works except the paragraph above.

Comment: You'll have to refine your question; there's not enough information to understand what you are trying to achieve. Your example is not informative.

Comment: @mortb I basically  want to highlight the text which is selected by the user but some of the text which contains some special tags doesn't get selected and above written text is an example of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.find()` in most browsers, although it may end up being removed from browsers in the future ([Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672395), [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64761)). Here's an answer about that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887719/96100

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're using `var searchText = document.getSelection().toString()` which doesn't take into account opening and closing tags inside your selection.
Instead you should try using `searchText = newNode.innerHTML`

Make these changes in your `getSelectedText` function, and you should be golden.
Some extra changes might be required for IE, though.

Comment: `searchText=sel.innerHTML;` in `GetSelectedText` function ?

Comment: @prateek No. ``sel`` is a selection Object, not a Node.
In your own code, you are creating a variable  ``newNode``, which you fill up with the selected content using ``range.surroundContents(newNode);``. After that, you should extract the contents using ``newNode.innerHTML``