# jQuery highlight pieces of text in an element across tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, selection, chaining

I want to select and return searched text using jQuery.

The problem is; parts of the text may be located in `<span>` or other inline elements, so when searching for `'waffles are tasty'` in this text: `'I'm not sure about <i>cabbages</i>, but <b>waffles</b> <span>are</span> <i>tasty</i>, indeed.'`, you wouldn't get any matches, while the text appears uninterrupted to people.

Let's use this HTML as an example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <span style="font-size: 1.2em">
    I
  </span>
  like turtles 
  <span>
    quite a
  </span>
  lot, actually.

  <span>
    there's loads of
  </span>
  tortoises over there, OMG

  <div id="child">
    <span style="font-size: 1.2em">
      I
    </span>
    like turtles 
    <span>
      quite a
    </span>
    lot, actually.

    TURTLES!
  </div>
</div>
```

With this (or similar) JavaScript:

```
$('div#parent').selectText({query: ['i like', 'turtles', 'loads of tortoises'], caseinsensitive: true}).each(function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#ffff00');
});
//The (hypothetical) SelectText function would return an array of wrapped elements to chain .each(); on them
```

You would want to produce this output: (without the comments, obviously)

```
<div id="parent">
  <span style="font-size: 1.2em">
    <span class="selected" style="background-color: #ffff00">
      I
    </span> <!--Wrap in 2 separate selection spans so the original hierarchy is disturbed less (as opposed to wrapping 'I' and 'like' in a single selection span)-->
  </span>
  <span class="selected" style="background-color: #ffff00">
    like
  </span>
  <span class="selected" style="background-color: #ffff00"> <!--Simple match, because the search query is just the word 'turtles'-->
    turtles
  </span> 
  <span>
    quite a
  </span>
  lot, actually.

  <span>
    there's
    <span class="selected" style="background-color: #ffff00">
      loads of
    </span> <!--Selection span needs to be closed here because of HTML tag order-->
  </span>
  <span class="selected" style="background-color: #ffff00"> <!--Capture the rest of the found text with a second selection span-->
    tortoises
  </span>
  over there, OMG

  <div id="child"> <!--This element's children are not searched because it's not a span-->
    <span style="font-size: 1.2em">
      I
    </span>
    like turtles 
    <span>
      quite a
    </span>
    lot, actually.

    TURTLES!
  </div>
</div>
```

The (hypothetical) `SelectText` function would wrap all selected text in `<span class="selected">` tags, regardless of whether parts of the search are located in other inline elements like `<span>`, '', etc. It does not search the child `<div>`'s contents because that's not an inline element.

Is there a jQuery plugin that does something like this? (wrap search query in span tags and return them, oblivious to whether parts of the found text may be located in other inline elements?)

If not, how would one go about creating such a function? [This function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257508/1233003)'s kinda what I'm looking for, but it doesn't return the array of selected spans and breaks when parts of the found text are nested in other inline elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: IDs are unique so you probably don't want to wrap all selected text in `<span id="selected">` tags, maybe a class? As for the question - why not go through all text nodes?

Comment: Right, forgot about that, let me just change that to classes.

That may be a good start, but how would I tell which parts of the text/inline nodes should be wrapped, and *how* they should be wrapped?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piece of cake! See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JCxMy/1/).

Folded notation:

```
$.each(
    $(...).findText(...), 
    function (){
        ...
    }
);
```

In-line notation:

```
$(...).findText(...).each(function (){
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: Wow. I presumed Regex would be impractical in this case, but damn, that's elegant. That implementation does have two problems though; 1. If you check out [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SoullessWaffle/JCxMy/2/) where I search for a full string, you can see that it doesn't get detected because the Regex inserts spaces in some places. 2. If you look at your original example, between `'I like'` and `'turtles'`, there's a space that gets highlighted twice because it's already in a `'selected'` span but for some reason gets wrapped in another while `'like'` does not even though they're siblings.

Comment: Thanks again. I see you inserted a space between `I` and `'ve` in the search query. It does detect it now but the HTML still has a space there where there originally wasn't one. Why is this happening? Is it the `EmulateSelection`'s regex or the `makeRegexp`'s regex? Btw, [this](http://gyazo.com/edd067fa03555fe769603b6848230f35) is what I described at problem two; it for some reason highlights the space individually even though it's already in a selection span. It's a minor problem that might be fixed by checking whether the element is in a selection span in the regex's `replace` functions.

Comment: Nesting of selection comes from repeating search phrases. If you really want superclear html, you need to eliminate `like` search if `like turtles` already setted or backward before.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to implement that.

Comment: Thanks for this. You saved me a ton of work. However, I ran into an issue. If you call .findText(...) on a jquery element that contains multiple elements, then the code seems to mess it up, replacing all elements after the first with clones of the first. The easiest solution was just to move the code from the main function into a separate function, and replace the main function with a call to map. Ex: 
$.fn.findText = function(params){
 return $(this).map(function(){
   return jquery_findText_main.call(this, params);
  });
};

Answer (score 3):

Three options:

- Use the browser's built-in methods for this. For the finding, IE has `TextRange` with its `findText()` method; other browsers (with the exception of Opera, last time I checked, which was a long time ago) have `window.find()`. However, `window.find()` [may be killed off without being replaced](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672395) at some point, which is not ideal. For the highlighting, you can use `document.execCommand()`.
- Use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library. There's a demo here: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html
- Build your own code to search text content in the DOM and style it.

The first two options are covered in more detail on this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887719/96100

Comment: Your Rangy library seems to do exactly what I'm looking for... Is there any way I could use it in a jQuery function and have that return the search result spans in an array for further chaining?

Comment: @SoullessWaffle: You could call getNodes() on the selection range after applying the 'selected' class. Something like `var spansWithClass = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getNodes([1], function(el) { return $(el).hasClass("selected"); })`

Comment: I'm having a little trouble deciphering what that example does exactly, because most of these functions seem to be poorly documented (unless I'm looking in the wrong place) e.g. the only reference I could find to getNodes is [this page](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#getNodes()), which confuses me slightly.

Comment: @SoullessWaffle: Sorry, I should have been clearer. `getNodes()` is Rangy-specific and is documented here: https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange#getNodes%28[Array_nodeTypes[,_Function_filter]]%29

Comment: Thanks, I think I get what that does now. Though I believe I'm doing something wrong [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SoullessWaffle/Wk69z/)...

Answer (score 1):

Since I just so happened to be working on a similar thing right now, in case you'd like to see the beginnings of my interpretation of "option 3", I thought I'd share this, with the main feature being that all text nodes are traversed, without altering existing tags. Not tested across any unusual browsers yet, so no warranty whatsoever with this one!

```
function DOMComb2 (oParent) {
    if (oParent.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var oNode = oParent.firstChild; oNode; oNode = oNode.nextSibling) {
            if (oNode.nodeType==3 && oNode.nodeValue) { // Add regexp to search the text here
                var highlight = document.createElement('span');
                highlight.appendChild(oNode.cloneNode(true));
                highlight.className = 'selected';
                oParent.replaceChild(highlight, oNode);

                // Or, the shorter, uglier jQuery hybrid one-liner
                // oParent.replaceChild($('<span class="selected">' + oNode.nodeValue + '</span>')[0], oNode);
            }
            if (oNode.tagName != 'DIV') { // Add any other element you want to avoid
                DOMComb2(oNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then search through things selectively with jQuery perhaps:

```
$('aside').each(function(){
    DOMComb2($(this)[0]);
});
```

Of course, if you have asides within your asides, strange things might happen.

(DOMComb function adapted from the Mozilla dev reference site
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)

Comment: I love this, it's very practical. One problem though; when it finds a match it will select the entire text node, not just the part that was found, because it would need to create new text nodes (probably with `textNode.splitText()`) to separate the result from the rest of the text and that would mess with the traversing. I'm also not sure how this would be implemented because I've never really messed with recursion before. I'm also unsure how I would implement partial matching because of this... (example in cont.)

Comment: (cont.) For example: You want to search for 'green apple', but not just 'apple'; what if the result is waiting to be found in this html?: `<span style="color: #00ff00">green</span> apple` if you (as a person) were to look at this, you could see that the text is definitely in there, space and everything, if you ignore the span tags. One way to possibly support this is to start searching for the full string, but if that's not found in the current text node then `str.slice(0, - 1)` the search string (remove last character) and only search the last few characters of the txtNode (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) ...because you're only looking for the first part of the search string, which would only be located in the last part of the text node. Repeat the `str.slice(0, - 1)` and break if a match is found, then look for the rest (`originalstr.substr(str.length-1)`) in the following sibling node (or child node, whichever comes first after the current text node), `if` the very first text characters of the text node are equal to that, `select` that part of the text (and the part of the text in the node we traversed before), `if not` simply continue traversing as normal.

Comment: You'd of course want to account for cases like these: Search: `red green blue` HTML: `<span style="color: #ff0000">red</span> <span style="color: #00ff00">green</span> <span style="color: #0000ff">blue</span>`, where the string is split in five (note the two spaces, which are text nodes) or more parts, so then you'd need to do more `str.slice(0, -1)` loops. Anyway, that's my take on this. Unfortunately, actually implementing it is going to be difficult (at least for me, I'm a recursion n00b), any tips or alternative methods?

Comment: I will definitely get back to you on this within the next 24h, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a draft as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7AfF/). The main steps:

I made a plugin for jQuery

```
$.fn.selectText = function(params){
    var phrases = params.query, 
        ignorance = params.ignorecase;
        wrapper = $(this);
    . . .
    return(wrapper);
};
```

Now I can call the selection as a `$(...).selectText({query:["tortoise"], ignorance: true, style: 'selection'});`

I know you want to have iterator after the function call, but in your case it is impossible, because iterator have to return valid jQuery selectors. For example:
`word <tag>word word</tag> word` is not valid selector.

After sanitizing the content of wrapper, for each search `makeRegexp()` makes personal regular expression.

Each searched  piece of html source goes to `emulateSelection()` and then `wrapWords()`

Main idea is to wrap in `<span class="selection">...</span>` each single piece of phrase not separated by tags, but not analyze the whole tree of nodes.

NOTE:

It's NOT working with `<b><i>...` tags in html. You have to make corrections in regexp string for it.
I not guarantee it will work with unicode. But who knows...

Comment: `word <tag>word word</tag> word` is indeed not a valid selector... Would returning the individual `<tag>`s (don't need the words, just the spans that contain the result) in an array not work? AFAIK this is how jQuery does it (html objects in an array if there are multiple)...
I'll probably use something like this as the wrapper for the main function, thanks.

Comment: but how about `word</tag>word</tag><tag>word` situation? it's absolutely non-jquery, non-tree wrappable situation.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand that example.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, we talking about iterators like `$.each($(...).searchText("..."),function (str){...});`.

Check the *David Herbert Lawrence* poem:

```
<div class="poem"><p class="part">I never saw a wild thing<br /> 
sorry for itself.<br /> 
A small bird will drop frozen dead from a bough<br />
without ever having felt sorry for itself.<br /></p></div>
```

Actually, after rendering, browser will understood it like this:

```
<div class="poem">
<p class="part">
<br>I never saw a wild thing</br> 
<br>sorry for itself.</br> 
<br>A small bird will drop frozen dead from a bough</br>
<br>without ever having felt sorry for itself.</br> 
</p>
</div>
```

For example, I looking for the phrase: `"wild thing sorry for"`. Therefore, I have to highligt the exerpt:

```
wild thing</br><br>sorry for
```

I can not wrap it like this `<span>wild thing</br><br>sorry for</span>`, then create jQuery selector by some temporary id="search-xxxxxx", and return it back -- it's wrong html. I can wrap each piece of text like this:

```
<span search="search-xxxxx">wild thing</span></br><br><span search="search-xxxxx">sorry for</span>
```

Then I have to call some function and return jQuery array of selectors:

```
return($("[search=search-xxxxx]"));
```

Now we have two "results": a) "*wild thing*"; b) "*sorry for*". Is it really what you want?

**OR**

You have to write you own `each()` function like another plugin to jQuery:

```
$.fn.eachSearch = function(arr, func){
    ...
};
```

where arr will be not an array of selectors, but *array of arrays* of selectors, like:

```
arr = [
    {selector as whole search},
    {[{selector as first part of search]}, {[selector as second part of search]}},
    ...    
]
```

Comment: The first example is similar to what I want; a jQuery function that can be called on an element and that [returns a wrapped set](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1302443/1233003) of selected elements, so  that those selected elements can be chained later. i.e. `$('div.poem').selectText({ignorecase: true, query: ['thing sorry', 'small bird', 'felt sorry']}).each(function(){$(this).css('background-color', '#ffff00');});`