# How can I get all selection html text node?

Tags: javascript, selection, textnode

I use `window.getSelection` to get the selected text, then I can use `getRangeAt` to get the actually `range` I select

but how can I get all text node I selected? in the `Range`'s property I can only get the `startContainer` and `endContainer`, what about the text outside the two container?

I want do some job like the `Diigo` did, I want use some tag wrap the text for highlight them, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide simple example use case in jsFiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5887719/96100