# exact text searches difficult in HTML DOM with Java string functions because of spaces, escape characters, tags

Tags: java, javascript, html, dom, full-text-search

My Android app performs text searches both in WebView DOM with Javascript and in XML DOM with Java. The issue is that text in HTML is written in forms that encompass multiple spaces, escape characters, tags. All these things are not displayed but spoil my text search in Java (for Javascript the solution is to use window.find() or textRange.findText() and some code is here: [Full text search in HTML ignoring tags / &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags)). Does a way exist to compute just rendered text as seen by the user (as if the HTML was rendered in a WebView) parsing XML in Java? Is having an hidden WebView performing search in Javascript the only solution?

Comment: extract `.innerText` from the DOM and search on that?

Comment: @Marc B Do you mean concatenating all innerText's of the entire DOM and searching in the resulting string?

Comment: if the html wrappers are screwing up your searches, then you'll have to eliminate the html. .innerText would accomplish that.

Comment: @MarcB: using .innerText could cause cross-browser issues depending on the CSS in use at the time it's called. better to use .textContent if you can to avoid white-space formatting discrepancies.

Comment: @Marc B Doesn't innerText compute collapsed spaces and escape characters?

Comment: either way, it's one way to get html-free contents of a dom node. whether or not those spaces/linebreaks are relevant to the OP's search engine isn't mentioned.

Comment: @Marc B what's relevant is what the user would see rendered by the WebView