# Javascript, HTML: Selection between two specific points

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range, selection

My app has to create a selection in DOM, based on specific points. There are three cases:
-between the beginning and a particular element identified by its id;
-between two elements identified by their respective id;
-between a particular element identified by its id and the end.
What's the code for selecting each of these three specific ranges?

Comment: Can you paste the specific HTML and attempts you have already made at solving this (if any)?

Comment: @Nick I am interested in performing text searches in that selection ranges. I am working to improve the code found at this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags

Comment: It's easy to create ranges for each of these cases with Range methdos such as [`setStartAfter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.setStartAfter). Regarding your comment, are you trying to perform text searches within just the content the user has selected?

Comment: @Tim Down No, I can have 0,1 (from start to it, from it to end ) or 2 ids so to perform the text search according to those 3 cases plus the 4th case where no id is available and the scope is the entire page. Is is not related to the search in the browser by the user although it is performed in a WebView on behalf of the user himself/herself.