# How to remove highlighted formatting of window.find(text)

Tags: javascript, android, text-search

After a text search in a `WebView` (Android) with JavaScript by means of `window.find(text)`, using code from [**this SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags), is successful and the corresponding text is highlighted.

Unfortunately I am not succeeding in finding the code for removing that formatting. I tried various methods (some from StackOverflow) without success, neither works what I deem the right one:

```
document.designMode = 'on';
document.execCommand('RemoveFormat', false, null);
document.designMode = 'off';
```

How can I remove the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by a trick, removing the span elements that are added by execCommand HiliteColor (assigned an attribute to original spans present at load time, if any):

```
addedSpans[i].outerHTML=addedSpans[i]innerHTML
```