# Android WebView: Are DOM or HTML changed when using document.execCommand "HiliteColor" (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, execcommand

My Android app features a WebView where text searches can be performed. I use the designMode='on'/window.find/execCommand technique to highlight text that matches the searched string as in this accepted answer [Full text search in HTML ignoring tags / &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags) .

Now, I need to know if DOM is affected by the hilighting because I read in a book about HTML5 that bold/italic text creates / tags inside the HTML, if I'm not wrong. Is it the same for hilighting in webkit Android webView? Or it is handled by the engine without affecting the DOM or HTML (no elements are added)?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that

```
<span>
```

elements are added.