# How to highlight search results in gridview using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, highlight

I am using a search box to sort my gridview according to the search text. I want to highlight the matching text in the gridview entered into the textbox.
This is my aspx page-

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="167px">
         </asp:TextBox>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                Text="Submit" Width="116px" />
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### code behind

```
public void bind()
{
     dt = g1.return_dt("select  * from tbl1 where id is  not null  " 
           + Session["Name"] + "  order by  compname ");
     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
         adsource = new PagedDataSource();
         adsource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
         adsource.PageSize = 10;
         adsource.AllowPaging = true;
         adsource.CurrentPageIndex = pos;
         btnfirst.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
         btnprevious.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
         btnlast.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
         btnnext.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
         GridView1.DataSource = adsource;
         GridView1.DataBind();
     }
     else
     {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();
     }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text != "")
    {
        Session["Name"] = string.Format("and  compname  like '%{0}%' or productcategory like '%{0}%' or country like '%{0}%'");
    }
    else
    {
         Session["Name"] = null;
    }
}
```

Please guide me how can I do this.

Comment: if you are able to match the row , simply change the background color for that row

Comment: Have you looked into GridView.RowDataBound Event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: @Mathias Actually I am already displaying my result in the gridview, I want that when I enter some text in the search box and click button then if that particular text is present in my gridview then it should get highlighted. Please guide me with above code of mine.

Comment: @Rex Hello, actually I am passing this text entered into search box as a where clause in my select query. And yes I am able to match the text but how can I highlight these text which is inside the gridview? I am quite confused about it. Please guide me.

Comment: It looks like you a rebinding the GridView with the user input as parameters for your query. I believe the Event will be triggered when you rebind the grid and there you can modify the cells of the row.

Comment: @Mathias Yes I am passing the text entered in the searchbox as a condition for my select query. I am holding the text entered in the textbox in a session variable and adding it with the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Modify the text in the relevant columns of you data table. (Find the text in each column and add an span with css class surrounding that text.) Here is a sample:

   ```
       foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
       {
           foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
           {
               string s = Convert.ToString(dr[dc.ColumnName]);
               s = s.Replace("Your Search Text", "<span style='color:RED'>Your Search Text</span>");
               dr[dc.ColumnName] = s;
           }
       }
   ```
2. You can use javascript for the same and let the browser do all the hardwork. (Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886858/full-text-search-in-html-ignoring-tags/5887719#5887719) for a sample.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the 1st suggestion might help me with this problem.
Sir, Can you provide me with a example for the same? Actually the sample you provided me was done using javascript.

Comment: Sir, Is there any option within the gridview property where I can provide highlight effect to the matching text?

Comment: I have added a sample code that you may use for first approach. Gridview do not have any such property to highlite text.

Comment: Sir, I have a doubt. Since, I am passing my search text entered into textbox through Session Variable then in that case How I am suppose to use the sample you provided me.
Please guide me sir.

Comment: Actually that changes the text colour to red, rather than highlighting it, but that is quite effective for my needs. Thanks +1 from me. :)  BTW To highlight it, simply modify the style to:  <span style='background-color:YELLOW'> ;)