# How to highlight search text in DataGridView in specific column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, highlight

Reference to this question [Highlight search in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788746/how-to-highlight-search-text-in-datagridview), solution works, but it higlight search string in whole datagridview.

My Question is, is it possible to higlight search text in specific column?

Here is copy of code from solution:

```
string keyValue = "Co"; //search text

private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == null) return;

    StringFormat sf = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;
    sf.FormatFlags = sf.FormatFlags | StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces | StringFormatFlags.DisplayFormatControl;
    e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);

    SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    if (((int)e.State & (int)DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) == 0)
        br.Color = Color.Black;

    string text = e.Value.ToString();
    SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, Font, e.CellBounds.Width, sf);

    int keyPos = text.IndexOf(keyValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (keyPos >= 0)
    {
        SizeF textMetricSize = new SizeF(0, 0);
        if (keyPos >= 1)
        {
            string textMetric = text.Substring(0, keyPos);
            textMetricSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(textMetric, Font, e.CellBounds.Width, sf);
        }

        SizeF keySize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text.Substring(keyPos, keyValue.Length), Font, e.CellBounds.Width, sf);
        float left = e.CellBounds.Left + (keyPos <= 0 ? 0 : textMetricSize.Width) + 2;
        RectangleF keyRect = new RectangleF(left, e.CellBounds.Top + 1, keySize.Width, e.CellBounds.Height - 2);

        var fillBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(fillBrush, keyRect);
        fillBrush.Dispose();
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, Font, br, new PointF(e.CellBounds.Left + 2, e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - textSize.Height) / 2), sf);
    e.Handled = true;

    br.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What do you want: Highlight only in one Column? Test for that column right at the start and return if you're not in it. Or highlight only the portion of the values that is the search string? This seems to be going on already.

Comment: The code highlit everything in datagridview, all rows in all columns that contain search text. I whant that it highlight all search cells in only one column, for example that I have 4 columns (Id, name, age, weight), I whant to highlite my search text only in name column.

Comment: As I said: Insert a condition: `if (e.Value == null) return;
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "name") return;`

Comment: @TaW can you post as answer, so I can upvote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when owner-drawing a `Control` the `Paint` event is used for the whole area.

The [DataGridView.CellPainting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx) event is different; it is called for every (visible) `Cell` in the DGV **separately**.

This means that you can completely dimiss it for some `Cells`, `Rows` or `Columns` simply by checking which Cell it is about to paint.

The [DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)  include 
`e.ColumnIndex` and `e.RowIndex`. You can solve your problem by testing for a certain column name like this:

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "name") return;
```

You could also test for a list of columns to include or exclude:

```
var names = new List<string> {"firstname", "lastname"};
string colName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
if (names.Contains(colName)) return;
```

Or hack it like this:

```
string names = " firstname lastname ";
string colName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
if (names.Contains(" " + colName + " ")) return;
```

`Rows` don't have `Names`, so you need to check for their indices. Note that the rows headers column as well as the column headers row have `-1` as their index and can be both painted and skipped like other cells.

Other noteworthy details on paint a DGV can be found on MSDN on [DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) , [PaintParts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs.paintparts(v=vs.110).aspx), [RowPrePaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint(v=vs.110).aspx) , [RowPostPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint(v=vs.110).aspx) ..