# TextHighlight in DataGridView on TextCell with WrapMode

Tags: c#, datagridview, highlight

[image]

in a DataGridView on WinForm i have :

```
dataGridViewAnzeige.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
dataGridViewAnzeige.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

to paint the background i do it at the CellPainting,
my search doing a "split search" to filter more results

but the measuring of the Wraped Text is faild, any ideas ?

the position on the second line fails ..

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1 && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "Id")
            {
                var suchtext = searchStringTextBox.Split(null);
                List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new List<Rectangle>();

                // Check data for search  
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchStringTextBox.Trim()))
                {
                    foreach (var txtSuche in suchtext)
                    {
                        String gridCellValue = e.FormattedValue.ToString();
                        // check the index of search text into grid cell.  
                        int startIndexInCellValue = gridCellValue.ToLower().IndexOf(txtSuche.Trim().ToLower());
                        // IF search text is exists inside grid cell then startIndexInCellValue value will be greater then 0 or equal to 0  
                        if (startIndexInCellValue >= 0)
                        {
                            e.Handled = true;
                            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
                            //the highlite rectangle  
                            Rectangle hl_rect = new Rectangle();
                            hl_rect.Y = e.CellBounds.Y + 2;
                            
                            //find the size of the text before the search word in grid cell data.  
                            String sBeforeSearchword = gridCellValue.Substring(0, startIndexInCellValue);
                            //size of the search word in the grid cell data  
                            String sSearchWord = gridCellValue.Substring(startIndexInCellValue, txtSuche.Trim().Length);
                            Size s1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, sBeforeSearchword, e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
                            Size s2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, sSearchWord, e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
                            if (s1.Width > 5)
                            {
                                hl_rect.X = e.CellBounds.X + s1.Width - 5;
                                hl_rect.Width = s2.Width - 6;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hl_rect.X = e.CellBounds.X + 2;
                                hl_rect.Width = s2.Width - 6;
                            }

                            //fail on textalign in middle
                            hl_rect.Height = s2.Height;

                            rectangleList.Add(hl_rect);

                        }
                    }

                }
                //color for showing highlighted text in grid cell
                SolidBrush hl_brush;
                hl_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
                //paint the background behind the search word 
                foreach(var recto in rectangleList)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hl_brush, recto);
                }
                
                hl_brush.Dispose();
                e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);

            }
        }
```

to paint the background i do it at the CellPainting, my search doing a "split search" to filter more results

but the measuring of the Wraped Text is faild, any ideas ?

the position on the second line fails ..

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution, please correct
or show the better solution

```
private void dataGridViewAnzeige_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1 && dataGridViewAnzeige.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "Id")
        {
            var suchtext = searchStringTextBox.Split(null);
            List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new List<Rectangle>();

            // Check data for search  
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchStringTextBox.Trim()))
            {
                foreach (var txtSuche in suchtext)
                {
                    //[0] split
                    //[1] banana
                    //[2] 08-19
                    String gridCellValue = e.FormattedValue.ToString();
                    // check the index of search text into grid cell.  
                    int startIndexInCellValue = gridCellValue.ToLower().IndexOf(txtSuche.Trim().ToLower());
                    int startIndexInCellSecondeRowValue = 0;
                    if (startIndexInCellValue >= 0)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
                        int indexOfN = gridCellValue.IndexOf("\n");

                        //the highlite rectangle  
                        Rectangle hl_rect = new Rectangle();
                        hl_rect.Y = e.CellBounds.Y + 2;

                        


                        //find the size of the text before the search word in grid cell data.  
                        String sBeforeSearchword = gridCellValue.Substring(0, startIndexInCellValue);
                        //size of the search word in the grid cell data  
                        String sSearchWord = gridCellValue.Substring(startIndexInCellValue, txtSuche.Trim().Length);
                        Size s1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, sBeforeSearchword, e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
                        Size s2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, sSearchWord, e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
                        if (s1.Width > 5)
                        {
                            hl_rect.X = e.CellBounds.X + s1.Width - 5;
                            hl_rect.Width = s2.Width - 6;

                            if (indexOfN != -1)
                            {
                                //if the index ob newline before searchword
                                if (startIndexInCellValue > indexOfN)
                                {
                                    int cellRow2Index = startIndexInCellValue - indexOfN;
                                    String breakWord = gridCellValue.Substring(indexOfN, cellRow2Index);
                                    Size s3 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, breakWord, e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
                                    hl_rect.X = e.CellBounds.X + 2 + s3.Width - 7;
                                    hl_rect.Y = e.CellBounds.Y + s2.Height + 2;
                                }
                            }
                                                      
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hl_rect.X = e.CellBounds.X + 2;
                            hl_rect.Width = s2.Width - 6;
                        }

                        // is a second row there?
                        // s text align in middle?
                        if (indexOfN == -1)
                        {
                            //no index ofN 
                            //textalign on artikelnumber in the middle
                            Size s4 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, gridCellValue, e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
                            //is the text width not longer than the cell, isnt't a word wrap
                            //and dthe text is in the middle of the cell
                            if (s4.Width < e.CellBounds.Width)
                            {
                                hl_rect.Y = e.CellBounds.Y + ((e.CellBounds.Height - s4.Height) / 2);
                            }
                        }

                        //fail on textalign in middle
                        hl_rect.Height = s2.Height;
                        rectangleList.Add(hl_rect);
                    }
                }

            }
            //color for showing highlighted text in grid cell
            SolidBrush hl_brush;
            hl_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
            //paint the background behind the search word 
            foreach (var recto in rectangleList)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hl_brush, recto);
            }

            hl_brush.Dispose();
            e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);

        }
    }
```

it works in my case...
[image]