# how to search and highlight terms excluding content inside a tag?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

`Our formula is this: We go out, we hit people in the mouth.<sup id="cite_ref-9" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-9">[9]</a></sup> The team went 5–4 overall`

I'm trying to match:

`in the mouth. The team went`

Basically trying to ignore the text inside the `<sup>` tag

I've adapted code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887719/926321).

```
document.designMode = "on";
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
while (window.find(search_string)) {
document.execCommand("backColor", false, "yellow");
}
sel.collapseToEnd();
document.designMode = "off";
```

While this ignores the tag, it doesn't ignore text within the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it's always a `sup` that you want to remove then you should be able to do something like

```
function stripSupFromText(text) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = text;
  div.removeChild(div.getElementsByTagName('sup')[0]);
  return div.innerText;
}
```